# Locking Rows Together for Sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to create a Gannt chart to manage project workflows. I would like to lock rows together for sorting purposes -- essentially, I want to sort by priority (high, low, medium), but keep the project's sub-tasks together. I've tried to use helper columns, but that's not working for me.

You can see in the image I've provided that I would need Project One to move as one unit, from initial edit to publish, and project two to move as a separate unit, from initial edit to publish. I want to sort based on the priority level, which is only a drop down option in the bolded project header row.

A number of people will be using this Excel doc and none of us are super Excel literate, so I would appreciate a simple solution if possible :) Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of the Gannt chart]

Comment: You could try a helper column starting in BO8 based on `=match("project*", b$8:b8, 0)` filled down as the primary sort criteria.

Comment: Your data has already an order like Project 1 to next including Priority High , Low,,, then what is  the issue,, also you have group,,, I think you have applied Group & Subtotal !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Place a filter on row 7 under the "Data" Ribbon -> Filter
2. Create a project column in column "A", to keep the sub-tasks together. This also makes sure the filter works correctly, as it only filters the rows of which the first column is filled.
3. Fill in the priority of every subtask

Now you can use the filter button to sort on priority.